# Instant App Failure to Rollout

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I did the all configuration for my instant app. Whenever I upload to the Play Store it says :

- Your site 'www.mywebsiteurl.com' has not been linked through the Digital
  Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the
  Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.
- You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site
  'www.mywebsiteurl.com' via a web 'intent-filter'.

**To be able to test my instant app, I uploaded my installable APK in draft**.

**Here is my installable app's Manifest File :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.as.myapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.as.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
  <uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
      tools:node="remove">
  </uses-permission>


  <application
      android:name="com.as.myapp.MyApp"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data
          android:name="default-url"
          android:value="https://www.mywebsitename.com/product/*" />
      <meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter
          android:autoVerify="true"
          android:order="1"
          >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebsitename.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebsitename.com"/>
        <data android:pathPattern="/product/*"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

**And this is my feature Manifest :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.as.myapp.feature.productdetail">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


  <application>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProductDetailActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data
          android:name="default-url"
          android:value="https://www.mywebsiteurl.com/product/*" />

      <meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>

      <intent-filter
          android:autoVerify="true"
          android:order="1"
          >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebsiteurl.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebsiteurl.com"/>
        <data android:pathPattern="/product/*"/>
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

And here my digital Asset Link Result : It says success.
[image: Digital Asset Links Result Picture]

What am I doing wrong? What causes this. 
I did everything what documentation says, and cannot figure out.

I'll appreciate for your help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Instant App Play Store Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629143/android-instant-app-play-store-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment, so I am gonna ask here. What was the package name in your JSON?

The package name should be of the installable app. And, is it okay to put your link details in both manifest files?

Comment: It is the same with my istallable package name. My links are somelike :

All is the same : 
www.mywebsite.com/product/12345 

I mean the feature that I implement is product detail page.